# Show that $\|\pi_c(y)-x\|_2^2 + \|\pi_c(y)-y\|_2^2 \leq \|x-y\|^2$, $\forall x$ in closed convex set $C$

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, projection

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the projection operator onto a closed convex set $\mathcal{C}$. Prove
> $\|\pi_c(y)-x\|_2^2 + \|\pi_c(y)-y\|_2^2 \leq \|x-y\|^2$, $\forall x \in \mathcal{C}$

In which $\pi_c(y)$ is the projection of $y$ on set $\mathcal{C}$.

I have tried to expand $\|x-y\|_2^2$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get
$\|\pi_c(y)-x\|^2 - \|\pi_c(y)-y\|_2^2 \leq \|x\|_2^2 -\|y\|_2^2-2\|\pi_c(y)\|(\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2)$
but this does not yield any useful result. I hope to get some insights

Comment: Naive observation:  It looks like the triangle inequality the wrong way.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Rather than the triangle inequality, one should think of this inequality as how equality in the Pythagorean theorem deforms (i.e. the law of cosines) if the right angle is obtuse instead.

Comment: You are right.  I overlooked the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is convex, then the constrained optimization problem
$$\min_z f(z) \text{ subject to } z \in C$$
has the following first-order optimality condition: a point $z^*$ is optimal if and only if
$$\langle \nabla f(z^*), x - z^* \rangle  \ge 0, \text{ for all } x \in C.$$
The intuition is that at the optimizer, feasible directions must have increasing gradient.

---

- Use this fact for $f(z) = \|y-z\|^2$ to show that $$\langle \pi_C(y) - y, x - \pi_C(y) \rangle \ge 0.$$
- Write $x-y = (x-\pi_C(y)) + (\pi_C(y) - y)$ to expand $\|x-y\|^2$. You will get the two terms on the left-hand side plus a cross term which you should check to be nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you! In fact, proving the projection theorem is the first part of the question. I can't believe that I missed the identity that $x-y = (x-\pi_C(y)) + (\pi_C(y) - y)$.